# Secure php script on localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I develop a php script software for a school. I install it on a school computer by using xammp server, but I'm facing a problem. How we secure our code on that system? Anyone can copy, edit or delete easily by going c/xammp/htdocs/  directory. What we do that my code not show anyone and how we can give trial period to customers?

Comment: use folder/file permissions

Comment: how use folder/file permission ??

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 7 operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit permissions in the folder htdocs, you can use [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7) to accomplish it. Make only accesible and/or viewable for your local user (and the user who will run XAMPP)